# Is there a method of pre-pending one text file to another much larger text file without cat?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a 330 Gb file and 10 lines of text I'd like to pre-pend to the file.  I don't particularly want to write out all 330 Gb again, just for 10 lines of text.  Is there some low level command that can prepend one file to another?

Comment: Maybe `dd` instead of `cat`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to avoid rewriting the file in some way. No file system I am aware of supports adding content to the beginning of a file without shifting the remaining contents.

Even

```
sed -i '1i NewLine' file
```

and similar methods (`cat`, `perl`) require a rewrite (and a tempfile, mostly).